# SQL statement convert in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have a `Products` table and `OrdersDetails` table. I want to display top 5 products by order count.

This is my SQL statement that I want to convert in LINQ:

```
SELECT TOP 5 P.ProductId, COUNT(OD.OrderId) AS 'Quantity Ordered' FROM Products AS P
INNER JOIN OrdersDetails AS OD
ON P.ProductId = OD.ProductId
GROUP BY P.ProductId
ORDER BY 'Quantity Ordered' DESC
```

Can somebody help me?

**EDIT**

I use LINQ to EF in my MVC project.

`Product` entity:

```
public partial class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        this.OrdersDetails = new HashSet<OrdersDetail>();
        this.ProductHistories = new HashSet<ProductHistory>();
        this.ProductReviews = new HashSet<ProductReview>();
    }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public Nullable<float> Discount { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ProducerName { get; set; }
    public string PaymentMethods { get; set; }
    public int Category { get; set; }
    public bool IsNew { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreateDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsEnable { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category1 { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrdersDetail> OrdersDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductHistory> ProductHistories { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductReview> ProductReviews { get; set; }
}
```

`OrdersDetail` entity:

```
public partial class OrdersDetail
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Quantity { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Price { get; set; }
    public Nullable<float> Discount { get; set; }

    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

This is my view model class:

```
public class ProductsViewModel
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Product Name is required.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Price is required.")]
    [Range(0.01, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Price must be a positive number.")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Discount is required.")]
    [Range(0, 99.99F, ErrorMessage = "Discount must be betwen 0 and 99,99.")]
    public float? Discount { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Quantity is required.")]
    [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Quantity must be a positive number or zero.")]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public string Size { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string ProducerName { get; set; }

    public string PaymentMethods { get; set; }

    public bool IsNew { get; set; }

    public bool IsEnable { get; set; }

    public SelectList CategoryList { get; set; }

    public string Category { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Category is required.")]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    public string Subcategory { get; set; }

    public int SubcategoryID { get; set; }

    public DateTime? CreateDate { get; set; }

    public string ProductImage
    {
        get { return Name.Replace(" ", string.Empty) + ".jpg"; }
        set { }
    }

    public HttpPostedFileBase UploadedFile { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ProductHistory> ProductHistory { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Review is required.")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Review { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Rate is required.")]
    [Range(1, 5, ErrorMessage = "Rate must be between 1 and 5")]
    public int RateProduct { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ProductReview> ProductReviews { get; set; }
}
```

Now I try something like this:

```
IEnumerable<ProductsViewModel> product = from pro in context.Products
                                                  join order in context.OrdersDetails
                                                      on pro.ProductId equals order.ProductId
                                                  group pro by pro.ProductId into g
                                                  select new ProductsViewModel { //maybe here I try to Count };
```

I want to display top 5 products with my view models. Maybe I must enter a new property in my model for Count?

Answer (score 2):

```
IEnumerable<ProductsViewModel> product = (from pro in context.Products
                                                  join order in context.OrdersDetails
                                                      on pro.ProductId equals order.ProductId
                                                  group pro by pro.ProductId into g
                                                  select new ProductsViewModel).take(5);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 var selct = (from b in context.Products
                             join ord in entities.OrdersDetails on b.ProductId equals ord.ProductId
                             select new { ProductID= b.ProductId , QuantityOrdered=context.OrdersDetails.Count() }
                          ).GroupBy(x => x.ProductId);
```